# How do I determine a basis of the vector space of polynomials degree 3 or less that satisfy $\int_{0}^{1}[xp'(x)-p(x)]=p(1)-2p(0)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have proven that the set of polynomials of degree 3 or less that satisfy $\int_{0}^{1}[xp'(x)-p(x)]=p(1)-2p(0)$ is indeed a subspace of $\mathscr{P}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$.

Now I need to find a basis. I found that all degree zero polynomials work. I've tried just using the monomials of each degree $(\lambda,0,0,0),(0,\lambda x,0,0),...,(0,0,0,\lambda x^{3})$ and I've found that none of the rest work...

It doesn't seem right to say that my basis is just one vector, but I'm at a loss on how to find anything else.

Comment: Why would the solutions be monomials?

Comment: @Bernard, I don't think that they are. They were just easy to check to see if they fall into the set or not. I'm not sure how else to explore this problem, hence my question.

Comment: It would have been a miracle if it had worked. I posted an explanation on the method;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p(x) = a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3$. Then the equation reads

$$
\int_0^1 x(b + 2cx + 3d x^2) - (a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3) \mathrm{d} x = a+b+c+d - 2a
$$
Evaluating the left-hand side gives
$$ 
 \frac b2 + \frac{2c}{3} + \frac{3d}{4} - a - \frac{b}{2} - \frac{c}{3} - \frac{d}{4} = a + b + c + d - 2a,
$$
or 
$$
 b = - \frac{2}{3} c - \frac{1}{2} d.
$$
Thus the general form is
$$
 p(x) = a + \left(- \frac{2}{3} c - \frac{1}{2} d \right)x + cx^2 + dx^3 = a + c \left( x^2 - \frac{2}{3} x \right) + d \left( x^3 - \frac{1}{2} x \right)
$$
and we can identify a basis $\left\{ 1, x^2 - \frac{2x}{3}, x^3 - \frac{x}{2} \right\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Integrating the first term on the left-hand side by parts gives
$$ \int_0^1 xp'(x) \, dx = [xp(x)]_0^1 - \int_0^1 p(x) \, dx = p(1)-\int_0^1 p(x) \, dx. $$
Therefore, putting this into the condition and cancelling terms, we find we only need
$$ \int_0^1 p(x) \, dx = p(0), $$
which we can also write as $$ \int_0^1 p(x)-p(0) \, dx = 0 $$. Obviously any constant satisfies this. To find the others, the condition is linear, so it's easy to stick in a general polynomial of degree 3 and see what happens; we find that for $p(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, we have
$$ \frac{a}{4}+\frac{b}{3}+\frac{c}{2} = 0. $$
Now just find two linearly independent choices of $a,b,c$, and you'll end up with 3 vectors once you include a constant, which is as you would expect for a 4-dimensional vector space with one constraint.

Comment: Sir, how did you get from $\int_{0}^{1}p(x)dx = p(0)$ to $\int_{0}^{1}(p(x)-p(0))dx=0$? It looks like the 2 coefficient on $p(0)$ went missing and it also looks like the p(0) went from being outside the integral to being part of the integral. I'm afraid I didn't follow how that happened.

Comment: Note that the integration by parts left $-2p(x)$ inside the integral on the left, so you can cancel $-2$. We also have $\int_0^1 dx = 1$, so one can multiply this by the constant $p(0)$, which can then be taken inside the integral.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Just set $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, compute both sides in function of $a,b,c,d$. There will result a (single) linear equation in $a, b,c,d$. This shows the space has codimension $1$, i.e. has dimension $4-1=3$. Thus one of the coefficients can be expressed in function of the three others. This defines an isomorphism of $\mathbf R^3$ with  the space of solutions. Take for instance the image under this isomorphism of the canonical basis of $\mathbf R^3$.